# node-rsa: Don't Need to Import Public Key?

Tags: node.js, security, encryption, rsa

This works:

```
import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';
const myPrivateKey = '........';
const key = new NodeRSA(myPrivateKey);
const message = '1234567890';
var encrypted = key.encrypt(message, 'base64', 'utf-8');
var clearMessage = key.decrypt(encrypted, 'utf8'); // contains '1234567890'
```

I thought RSA encrypted using a public key and decrypted using a private key. But in the above code, it appears I never have to give `NodeRSA` my public key.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RSA a public key is usually a subset of the private key. If you're importing the private key then all the fields that a public key would contain are there and can be used.